# How to get Transmission package Timestamp from ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am trying to make an Indoor positioning system using ESP8266 as a beacon, how do I get the transmission package timestamp from router to ESP8266 and vice-versa?

Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: what is a transmission package timestamp?

Comment: it's the timestamp that's attached to a package every time it is sent from the receiver to the router or vice-versa

Comment: What do you hope to use the timestamp for?

Comment: I'm going to compare the received package timestamp from ap to dongle and vice versa to get the distance between the ap and dongle

Answer (score -1):

You can use timestamp from NTP client and attach it

Install NTPclient library from Arduino library manager
This library uses WiFiUdp library to connect to the NTP server, so download that too

Then you can just update the time every time your sending/receiving something and log it as and how you see fit!

Comment: this answer is so wrong. it doesn't answer the question and it doesn't answer right the question I assume it answers

Comment: How do I access it though?

Comment: @Juraj oh I see! maybe I misunderstood the question, I definitely didn't know what ```Indoor positioning system using ESP8266 as a beacon``` was! I was working on sending sensor data to database and added this NTP client to get time every time i sent data to database, so i thought the requirement was the same and hence suggested it! would love to hear your thoughts!